# How do we know if a set of bits forms a real or an integer number?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

Given a set of bits (64) how does the computer know that they belong to either a real number or to an integer?

Comment: Isn't that decision left to whoever implemented the architecture (or better yet the compiler)? Maybe you can clarify your question or add an example.

Comment: Do you mean a _real_ number or an _integer_? The computer won't know, but the programmer/compiler will use different instructions depending on whether it's one or the other.

Comment: Weak typed hardware (TM)

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a programming question? Where did you get the 64 bits from?

Comment: it's the same as asking whether it's a signed or unsigned integer - it could be anything, depending on how you interpret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer does not know and does not care.

It is up to the program to know whether that particuliar memory should be used as an integer (long), as a real (double) or as a character array.

Depending on the language, the same values in same can be used at different moments as a double precision real, as a long integer or 8 bytes

Example using C language :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double r = 12.5;
    void *pt = &r;
    long long unsigned int *up = pt;
    char *cp = pt;
    int i;

    printf("Real : %f\n", r);
    printf("Int  : %llx\n", *up);
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        printf("%02x", cp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs :

```
Real : 12.500000
Int  : 4029000000000000
0000000000002940
```

It is formally undefined behaviour to convert a float pointer into an int pointer but it works like that on a little endian 32 bits system.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern computers do not have hardware type tags, so a 64-bit chunk of storage is, well, a 64-bit chunk of data, meaning something. It could be a signed 64-bit integer, it could be an unsigned 64-bit integer, a 64-bit float, two 32-but (repeat previous data types). Maybe it's 4 16-bit integers? Maybe it's a 7-character string, with a leading 8-bit string length?

The distinction between these would be down to whatever machine instructions are actually executed. Thus, the typing is determined by the instructions, not by the memory storage.